# Pie Chart dentro de modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal, jquery-remodal

Estou montando uma página com um link que abre um modal. Nesse modal quero que abra um pie chart, mas o modal abre em branco e só depois que atualizo a página com o modal aberto é que aparece o pie chart. 
Detalhe: estou usando bootstrap, AdminLTE para fazer o pie chart e um plugin chamado remodal para o modal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>AdminLTE 2 | Inline Charts</title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/remodal.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/remodal-default-theme.css">
    </head>
    <style>
        .remodal-bg.with-red-theme.remodal-is-opening,
        .remodal-bg.with-red-theme.remodal-is-opened {
          filter: none;
        }

        .remodal-overlay.with-red-theme {
          background-color: #c0c0c0;
        }

        .remodal.with-red-theme {
          background: #fff;
        }
      </style>
    <body>
     <a href="#modal2">Modal №1</a>   
    <div data-remodal-id="modal2" role="dialog">
      <br>
      <div style="height:250px;width:250px">
        <canvas id="pieChart"></canvas>
      </div><!-- /.box-body -->

    <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
        <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- ChartJS 1.0.1 -->
        <script src="plugins/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <!-- FastClick -->
        <script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
        <!-- AdminLTE App -->
        <script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
        <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
        <script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
        <!-- page script -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/remodal.js"></script>

    <!-- Eventos -->
    <script>
    //  Usage:
    //  $(function() {
    //
    //    // In this case the initialization function returns the already created instance
    //    var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();
    //
    //    inst.open();
    //    inst.close();
    //    inst.getState();
    //    inst.destroy();
    //  });
      //  The second way to initialize:
      $('[data-remodal-id=modal2]').remodal({
        modifier: 'with-red-theme'
      });//----FIM-----//

    //-------------CONFIGURAÇÕES DO GRÁFICO----------
            //- PIE CHART -
            //-------------
            // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
            var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
            var PieData = [
              {
                value: 700,
                color: "#f56954",
                highlight: "#f56954",
                label: "Chrome"
              },
              {
                value: 500,
                color: "#00a65a",
                highlight: "#00a65a",
                label: "IE"
              },
              {
                value: 400,
                color: "#f39c12",
                highlight: "#f39c12",
                label: "FireFox"
              },
              {
                value: 600,
                color: "#00c0ef",
                highlight: "#00c0ef",
                label: "Safari"
              },
              {
                value: 300,
                color: "#3c8dbc",
                highlight: "#3c8dbc",
                label: "Opera"
              },
              {
                value: 100,
                color: "#d2d6de",
                highlight: "#d2d6de",
                label: "Navigator"
              }
            ];
            var pieOptions = {
              //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
              segmentShowStroke: true,
              //String - The colour of each segment stroke
              segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
              //Number - The width of each segment stroke
              segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
              //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
              percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
              //Number - Amount of animation steps
              animationSteps: 100,
              //String - Animation easing effect
              animationEasing: false,
              //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
              animateRotate: false,
              //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
              animateScale: false,
              //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
              responsive: true,
              // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              //String - A legend template
              legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
            };
            //Create pie or douhnut chart
            // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
            pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
    //---FIM---//
        </script>
    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Eu tive um problema semelhante utilizando ChartJs e AngularJs. No meu caso o problema era porque eu estava tentando desenhar antes de o modal estar totalmente aberto. Para arrumar eu coloquei uma function no clique para abrir o modal, e nela eu montava os elementos canvas dentro do modal para depois desenhar o gráfico.

Comment: Assim: <button onclick="modal()">Modal №1</button>   
<div data-remodal-id="modal2" id="modal2" role="dialog">
    <br>
</div>
    <script>
    function modal(){
       $('[data-remodal-id=modal2]').remodal({
                modifier: 'with-red-theme'
        });
       $("#modal2").addClass("js").before('<div style="height:250px;width:250px"><canvas id="pieChart"></canvas></div>');
    }

Comment: Tentei assim para criar o canvas dentro do modal, mas ñ deu certo